# Как применить стиль к элементу на определенной странице, используя CSS и не создавая классов?

Tags: html, css3

Как изменить у `h3` `font-style` на `italic` только на одной странице, используя CSS и не создавая классов?

Comment: javascript'ом проверить страницу, если нужная - изменить стиль. `if (location.href== '/mypage') { //заголовок.стиль = italic }`

Comment: The following criteria will apply:
 All formatting must be done with CSS.

Comment: если структура у страниц разная, то можно привязаться у конкретной страницы к предыдущим блокам и использовать контекстные селекторы: `header + .main > h3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можете это сделать

```
<h3 style="font-style: italic!important;">Текст</h3>
```

Но при этом в основном css не должно у h3 стоять !important

Comment: Почему не должно?

Comment: Если в основном будет !important то будет действовать правило основного css. То бишь внутри h3 не главное правило.

Comment: inline important перебьёт что угодно https://jsfiddle.net/uqppL5tb/

Comment: У меня не всегда срабатывает, почему не разобрался, приходится изощряться. Ну в целом я ТСу ответ дал, попробует он его или нет дело сугубо его личное, но должно сработать на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 2):

Не то чтобы это невозможно вообще, но поддержка плохая:

```
@document 
  /* Правила для конкретной страницы */
  url(http://example.com/),

  /* Правила для страницы, URL которой начинается с ... */
  url-prefix(http://example.com/snippets/),

  /* Правила для страниц определенного домена */
  domain(example.com),

  /* Правила для всех https страниц */
  regexp("https:.*")
{

  /* Сами стили */
  h3 { font-style: italic; }

}
```

[`@document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document)

> CSS at-rule, ограничивающее действие стилей внутри себя на
>   основе URL документа.

**Внимание:** это экспериментальная технология!
Полная поддержка только с использованием префикса `-moz` в Firefox старше 6.0 версии.